# How to prove this matrix bound

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let an $m$ by $n$ matrix $A\in\mathbb C^{m\times n}$. Denote $M=\max_i\sum_{j=1}^n|A_{ij}|$ and $N=\max_j\sum_{i=1}^m|A_{ij}|$. Prove for any two vectors $x\in\mathbb C^m$ and $y\in\mathbb C^n$, we have
$$\left\vert x^TAy\right\vert\leq\sqrt{MN}|x||y|$$

---

Here's what I think:

$$|x^TAy|=\left|\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_iy_j\right|\leq\sqrt{\sum_j\left(\sum_iA_{ij}x_i\right)^2\cdot\sum_jy_j^2}\leq\left|y\right|\sqrt{\sum_j\left(\sum_iA_{ij}^2\cdot\sum_ix_i^2\right)}=|x||y|\sqrt{\sum_{ij}A_{ij}^2}$$

But how do I prove $$\sum_{ij}A_{ij}^2\leq MN$$

---

**Edit:**

My idea was proved to be wrong. But how do I prove the original inequality?

Comment: Which norm are you considering in $\mathbb C^{m\times n}$?

Comment: @dafinguzman L2 norm

Comment: I gave it a shot but could only prove $|x^TAy|\leq (mn)^\frac 14(MN)^\frac 12||x||\,||y|| $.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you want to prove is not true (for example, the identity matrix $A$). Consider a different approach, when in the second inequality you do not go so above the threshold.

Comment: How do I prove the original one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left\Vert X\right\Vert$ denote the spectral norm of $X$. Also, let $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_{p\to p}$ denote the matrix norm induced by the $\ell_p$-norm:

$$\left\Vert X\right\Vert_{p\to p}=\max_{v\neq 0} \frac{\left\Vert Xv\right\Vert_p}{\left\Vert v\right\Vert_p}.$$

Let $v$ be the principal eigenvector of $A^*A$, i.e., a unit $\ell_2$-norm vector for which we have $A^*Av=\sigma^2 v$ where $\sigma^2=\left\Vert A^*A\right\Vert=\left\Vert A\right\Vert^2$. It follows that $$\frac{\left\Vert A^*Av\right\Vert_1}{\left\Vert v\right\Vert_1}=\frac{\left\Vert \left\Vert A\right\Vert^2v\right\Vert_1}{\left\Vert v\right\Vert_1}=\left\Vert A\right\Vert^2.$$ Therfore,

$$\left\Vert A\right\Vert^2\leq\left\Vert A^*A\right\Vert_{1\to 1}=\max_{u,v\neq 0}\frac{\left\vert u^*A^*Av\right\vert}{\left\Vert u\right\Vert_\infty\left\Vert v\right\Vert_1}\\
\leq \max_{u,v\neq 0}\frac{\left\Vert Au\right\Vert_\infty\left\Vert Av\right\Vert_1}{\left\Vert u\right\Vert_\infty\left\Vert v\right\Vert_1}=\left\Vert A\right\Vert_{\infty\to\infty}\cdot \left\Vert A\right\Vert_{1\to 1}.$$ It is straightforward to show that $M=\left\Vert A\right\Vert_{\infty\to \infty}$ and $N=\left\Vert A\right\Vert_{1\to 1}$. The result then follows using the fact that $\left\vert x^*Ay\right\vert\leq\left\Vert A\right\Vert\left\Vert x\right\Vert\left\Vert y\right\Vert$.

Comment: Why is it that you can compute $\left\Vert A^*A\right\Vert_{1\to 1}$ as $\max_{u,v\neq 0}\frac{\left\vert u^*A^*Av\right\vert}{\left\Vert u\right\Vert_\infty\left\Vert v\right\Vert_1}$?

Comment: Or, more generally, is it true that you can compute $\left\Vert A^*A\right\Vert_{p\to p}$ as $\max_{u,v\neq 0}\frac{\left\vert u^*A^*Av\right\vert}{\left\Vert u\right\Vert_q\left\Vert v\right\Vert_p}$, where $p$ and $q$ are conjugate indexes?

Comment: That's correct. I used the fact that $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ are dual of each other.

Comment: Could you point me to a reference? It seems that I don't know where to look for that formula.

Comment: See the definition and the examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: then $\Vert A^*A\Vert_{1\to1}=\max_v \frac{\Vert A^*Av\Vert_1}{\Vert v \Vert_1}=\max_v \frac{1}{\Vert v \Vert_1} \left(\max_u \frac{| u*A^*Av|}{\Vert u \Vert_\infty} \right).$ Thanks a lot!